# jquery get previous a href

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello i want to get the previous clicked a href. The site doesnt reload.

```
<li><a href="#section3"><b>Restaurant</b></a></li>
```

This jumps to div id=section3

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('a[href*="section"]').bind('click',function(event){
                var $anchor = $(this);
                var addressValue = $(this).attr("href");

                $(addressValue).css("display","block");  
                $('html, body').animate({ 
                    scrollLeft: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().left
                }, 1000,'easeInOutExpo',function(){

                });   
      var allsections = '#section2,#section3,#section4,#section5,#section6,#section7,#section8,#section9,#section10,#section11,#section12,  #section13,#section14,#section15,#section16,#section17,#section18,#section19,#section20,#section21,#section22';  
       var removedsec = allsections.replace(addressValue+",",'');
         //   alert(removedsec);
         setTimeout(function () {  
                $(removedsec).removeAttr("style");  
          }, 100)
             });
        });
    </script>
```

The divs are all displayed none. If i click on a link it set the actual div on block. 
I need to let the previous clicked link to be displayed block to. If than the next link is clicked the first div should be set do display none.

Could i explain how i want it :D

Comment: First declare global_var='' and store the addressValue in global_var after displaying the current div.

Answer (score 0):

Cancel the default event on your link:

```
$('a[href*="section"]').bind('click',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    //.
    //.
    //rest of your code
});
```

Comment: i dont get the a href of the previous event :) I need the actual href and the previous

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution would be to set a class to all section divs. like  and then when you click on any section, just hide them all:

```
$(function() {
        $('a[href*="section"]').bind('click',function(event){
            $(".section").hide();
            var $anchor = $(this);
            var addressValue = $(this).attr("href");
            ...........................
```

Hide() has no effect on already hidden divs, so you do not have to know which one is visible.

Other solution would be to iterate trough them and check .is(":visible") to see which one is not hidden.

But I would recommend first solution, it is fast and working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function() {
           var prev_div = '';
            $('a[href*="section"]').bind('click',function(event){
                var $anchor = $(this);
                var addressValue = $(this).attr("href");
                if(prev_div.length) {
                   $(prev_div).css("display","block");     
                }
                $(addressValue).css("display","block");
                prev_div = addressValue;  
                $('html, body').animate({ 
                    scrollLeft: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().left
                }, 1000,'easeInOutExpo',function(){

                });   
      var allsections = '#section2,#section3,#section4,#section5,#section6,#section7,#section8,#section9,#section10,#section11,#section12,  #section13,#section14,#section15,#section16,#section17,#section18,#section19,#section20,#section21,#section22';  
       var removedsec = allsections.replace(addressValue+",",'');
         //   alert(removedsec);
         setTimeout(function () {  
                $(removedsec).removeAttr("style");  
          }, 100)
             });
       var removedsec1 = allsections.replace(prev_div+",",'');
         //   alert(removedsec1);
         setTimeout(function () {  
                $(removedsec1).removeAttr("style");  
          }, 100)
             });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store the active and the previous section in an array:

```
(function () {
    var history = [];
    $('a[href*="section"]').bind('click', function (e) {
        // prevent default behavour of your link
        e.preventDefault();
        // determine the section related to this.href
        var $section = $('.section').filter($(this).attr('href'));
        // add it to our history array
        history.push($section);
        // if the history contains more than 2 items, remove the first
        if(history.length > 2) {
            history.shift();
        }
        // hide all sections
        $(".section").hide();
        // show the two sections in history
        $(history).show();
        // return false, also to prevent the link's default behaviour
        return false;
    });
}());
```